# JS: Is a closure still a closure with an argument?

Tags: javascript

Most of the closure examples I have seen have a variable defined in the parent function but I can't think of how that would come in handy.

```
function test() {
    let name = "Roger";

    return function() {
        return "My name is " + name;
    };
}
```

Would the parent function taking an argument still constitute as being a closure?

```
function test(name) {
    return function() {
        return "My name is " + name;
    };
}

let firstName = test("Roger");

firstName = "My name is Roger";
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes, whether the variable is an argument or just declared inside the function body, it still has the property of the closure - it will remain accessible (indirectly, through the inner function call, and will not be garbage collected) as long as a reference to the returned function exists.

For a similar example:

```
const getRogerSentence = (() => {
    function test(name) {
        return function() {
            return "My name is " + name;
        };
    }

    return test("Roger");
})();
```

The `'Roger'` string created in the body of the IIFE is passed to the `test` function and not referenced anywhere else, but since the `test` function takes the argument and *closes over it* due to the returned function, the `name` remains in existence as long as `getRogerSentence` exists.

Answer (score 0):

Yes, the function is acting as a closure for the new function that is created within it:

[image]